# Why $\Theta^2 = 1$ suggests the $\Theta$-invariant space only consists of 1-dimension subspaces, for an antilinear operator $\Theta$?

Tags: linear-algebra, time-reversal-symmetry

Let $S$ be a subspace of the Hilbert space, and let $S$ be invariant under an $\textit{antilinear}$ operator $\Theta$, i.e. for every $\vert\psi\rangle$, $\Theta\vert\psi\rangle \in S$. I learned that if $\Theta^2 = 1$, then $S$ only consists of 1-dimension subspaces. This means for every subspace $S_i$, dim$S_i = 1$, and for $\vert\psi\rangle$ in $S_i$, $\Theta\vert\psi\rangle = \vert\psi\rangle$.

I know if $\vert\psi\rangle$ and $\Theta\vert\psi\rangle$ are linearly dependent, they are multiples of each other. In this case, they are the same thing, since we can regard $\Theta\vert\psi\rangle$ as a vector spanned by ${\vert\psi\rangle}$ subspace. But, if $\vert\psi\rangle$ and $\Theta\vert\psi\rangle$ are linearly independent, things get complicated, and I don't know how it leads to a contradiction if $\exists S_i$ where dim$S_i > 1$.

Comment: I do not understand. Take the standard complex conjugation of $L^2$ functions. It satisfies the requirement but the whole infinite dimensional $L^2$ space is invariant under it.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Is your $L$ the same thing as the $\Theta$ operator in the question?

Comment: No, $L^2(R)$ is the Hilbert space of classical wavefunctions. Your $\Theta$ is the complex conjugation, point by point, of the wave functions.